# If $AX=XA$ for all $X$, then $A = \alpha I$ for some $\alpha$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ be a $2 \times 2$ real matrix such that $AX=XA$ for all $2 \times 2$ real matrices $X$. Show that $A= \alpha I$ for some $\alpha ∈R.$

I am absolutely stuck, i thought $X$ and $A$ are inverses of each other, but realised that's only if $AX=XA=I$. And therefore, I'm stuck.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:
Put $$
X=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&0
\end{pmatrix},
$$
to get the elements off-diagonal are $0$.
Then put
$$
X=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
0&0
\end{pmatrix}$$
to get fact that the elements on the main-diagonal are the same.

Comment: I don't get how this helps considering X can be any 2x2 real matrix

Comment: You must have $AX=XA$ for any $2\times 2$ real matrix. So, you can choose $X$'s as I suggested above.

Answer (score 1):

It's a classic exercise : 
Let $E_{i,j}$ be the matrix with one 1 on the line i and the column j.
We can write :
$$
E_{1,2}A = AE_{1,2}
$$
so
$$
a_{1,2}= a_{2,1}= 0 \\
a_{1,1}= a_{2,2}  
$$
which is your results.
The result stands for all dimension (and I encourage you to do the exercise for dimension = 3).